# ruby on railsでのエラー： ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

初心者です。
ruby on railsで開発を始めたばかりですが、エラーの解決方法がわからなくて困っております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この様なエラーがでてコマンド上にTo resolve this issue,のあとに続くコマンドを実行してみたのですが同じようなエラーがでました。解決方法がわかる方がいたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 「同じようなエラー」とは、少し違うエラーメッセージでしょうか? 具体的に示すと解決の糸口になるかもしれません。(エラーメッセージは画像では無くテキストで記載するのが望ましいです。)

Comment: 説明が上手くなくてすみません。流れは、ブラウザで表示させようとする→画像1枚目のactivependingerrorが出る→コマンド上でマイグレーションする→画像2枚目のコマンド上でのエラーがでる→rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=developmentを実行→

Comment: 補足説明はコメントでは目立ちにくいですし、改行等も使えませんから、質問下にある[edit]から本文に追記していただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

migrationファイル（db/migration）に、適用されてないものがある状態です。

---

`rails g scaffold`、`rails g model`、`rails g migration`などmigrationファイルが生成されるコマンドを実行した後に`rails db:migrate`コマンドを実行していないとこの例外が発生します。
`rails db:version`と打ってみてください。これが現在のversionです。
通常は、このVersionとmigration ファイルの最新のもののVersionが一致していると思います。

もし、この状況になった状態で、色々いじってしまってにっちもさっちもいかなくなってしまっていたら、`rails db:migrate:reset RAILS_ENV=development`と実行してください。
このコマンドを実行すると、DBをdropして、migrationファイルを頭から全部実行してくれます。
データは全て消えますが、DBとmigrationファイルの整合性は保たれます。

Answer (score 0):

Railsで、モデルを作成したあとは、必ずrake db:migrate. もしくは、 rails5なら、rails db:migrateとコマンドを実行してください。

砕いて説明すると、現在のあなたの状況は active recordと呼ばれる機能で、データベースを作りますよーと宣言している状態です。

この宣言している状態から、データベースに何をどうするのか確定させるのが、前途のコードです。

この辺りが参考になると思います

https://railsguides.jp/active_record_migrations.html#%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Answer (score -2):

`r‌​ails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

ではなく、

`bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

がマイグレーションのコマンドになります。

`rails`コマンドと`rake`コマンドがあるので混同しないようにして見てください。